Get Diff Stat for Pull Request BitBucket Server REST API
I am working on some adapter implementation for Bitbucket Server. There is one already for Bitbucket Cloud, I want to be able to get the diffstat for a pull request. I could easily do that for Cloud by calling the REST API endpoint https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-pullrequests/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-pullrequests-pull-request-id-diff-get
I want same for Server version and to get the lines added and removed Or some other suggested alternatives that allows me to get this datas on the Server REST API version of Bitbucket

Which version of BB Server?

I've no idea. Its probably the latest. I don't know because we're doing the integration for a customer and I'm not the one in charge of interfacing with them or asking questions directly.
